# Pasting Gif images into Facebook copied from App

Tags: ios, facebook, uipasteboard

I have an app which plays GIF images (animations). I can copy it using UIPasteBoard and paste it into iPhone's native text app or attach it mail.

How can i paste it into Facebook app's text message area or status area?

Is it achievable from app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't support animated gifs.